# I need help filter map in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

```
{Prov ? data.filter((item) => {
     return item.address[0] === Prov 
     // return item.address[item.address.filter(x => {return x === Prov})] === Prov
    }).map((item) => {
    return (
      ard(item)
    )
    }) : data.map((item) => {
        return (
       card(item)
      )
 })}
```

I have an object that is data in data There is an object that is an address another object how can I output without having to point to an existing property

return item.address[0] === Prov  // run OK
return item.address[item.address.filter(x => {return x === Prov})] === Prov  // run failer

Comment: Can you please share your sample data? Based on what I understand, you can do `item.address.includes(Prov)` but will need to see data to be sure

Comment: Prov can be called a const

Comment: And what does `item` look like? Can you share a sample JSON in your question?

Comment: "Fashion": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "#2730 Áo sơ mi nam ngắn tay hàng nhập",
      "price": 120.000,
      "saleprice": 140.000,
      "percent": 40,
      "sold": 248,
      "address": [
        "Hồ Chí Minh",
        "Đà Nẵng"
      ]
    },

Comment: "id": 2,
      "name": "#2730 Áo sơ mi nam ngắn tay hàng nhập",
      "price": 120.000,
      "saleprice": 140.000,
      "percent": 40,
      "sold": 248,
      "address": [
        "Hà Nội",
        "Quảng Ninh",
        "Hải Phòng"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "#2730 Áo sơ mi nam ngắn tay hàng nhập",
      "price": 120.000,
      "saleprice": 140.000,
      "percent": 40,
      "sold": 248,
      "address": [
        "Hà Nội"
      ]
    },

Comment: My suggestion will work